# How to create transparent Rectangle in Mfc c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I want to create a rectangle total transparent i try this code. Any idea how to do that?

```
 BOOL CHtmlDlgTestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {

        if (pMsg->message == WM_MOUSEMOVE && (pMsg->wParam & MK_LBUTTON))
        {
            CPoint p = pMsg->pt;
            ScreenToClient(&p);
            CRect r(10, 15, 380, 50);
            CDC* pCDC = GetDC();
            pCDC->Rectangle(r);
            CBrush brush;


            brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
            pCDC->FillRect(&r, &brush);



            if (r.PtInRect(p))
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0);
                SendMessage(WM_NCLBUTTONUP, HTCAPTION, 0);
                return 1;
            }

        }
        return CDHtmlDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
    }
```

This is mfc c++ code example.

Comment: What do you mean "total transparent"? If it was totally transparent you wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: Thats what i want. I don't want to see.

Comment: This is very difficult because `CDHtmlDialog` dialog is a webBrowser control which is sitting in a different thread. The non-client area of the window is part of MFC's process, it lets you gain limited control only to move the window and stuff. Going too far in to `PreTranslateMessage` can get you in trouble because messages can turn in to recursive calls. Can I ask what you are trying to do? There is lot of things you can do with plain HTML5 and javascript. Another option is `CHtmlEditCtrl`, you can put these controls inside a `CDialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: How the hell do you want to create a transparent rectangle, if you created a solid brush and after did a FillRect with it?

If you wanted to do that using a brush, you would have to go with one "that not paints anything" like:

```
brush.CreateStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
```

May be you wanted a rectangle with an opaque border and transparent interior. In that case, in addition to the null brush, the object you need to create is a CPen.

```
CPen p(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(255, 255, 0));
pCDC->SelectObject(&p);
pCDC->Rectangle(r);
```

Secondly, I think the `DrawEdge` function is the simplest way to go if you dont' care about the border color (the colors are fixed; search DrawEdge in Google images to see what I mean).